# Nexus 5 onCreate() method calls when go back to previous activity

Tags: android, oncreate, android-4.4-kitkat, activity-lifecycle

i have a problem about activity lifecycle in **nexus 5**. When i go back to previous activity **onCreate()** method calls on previous activity. Normally it should call **onStart()** method when go back to previous activity.

In other devices with android 4.3 or lower i didn't see any behaviour like this.

In manifest file i've defined

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

for all activies.

Is it something about **android 4.4.2** and how to fix it?

Comment: It is really bad practice to add those configChanges to your activity. It causes all sorts of trouble and probably mean you're going down the wrong road with your design. EDIT: And what is wrong with calling onCreate again? Your design should be able to handle activities being killed and recreated at all times.

Comment: It may be, if your activity destroyed due memory problems. Check that onDestroy of previous activity is called. Also, don't you close previous activity using finish() after starting the second one?

Comment: There is also a developer option to destroy all activities by default. Maybe you checked that. It's at the bottom of the developer options first entry below apps header.

Comment: @hcpl thank you, my problem is solved. it was all about the developer options. if you write it as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @NaCI no problem, someone was ahead of me on creating that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a developer option to destroy all activities by default.You may have checked that. It should be at the bottom of the developer options on the first entry below the apps header.

Answer (score 1):

ethod calls on previous activity. Normally it should call onStart() method when go back to previo close previous activity using developer options first entry belohank you, my problem is solved. it was all abo